# Scaling an image in Xamarin form

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have been trying to make my image and text to scale when the forms appears, but i still cannot get the effect.

- I have a "GetStarted" process with 4-5 pages that is launched when the app starts.
- Each page has a Image in the middle
- Title-Description after image

What Have I done.

1. I have given an "x:Name" to the svgcachedImage - labelTitle and LabelDescription
2. In the constructor of my page I have used the scale method to create the effect
3. Didnt work

What I am trying to create

If you  go to this link https://www.syncfusion.com/blogs/post/create-a-wizard-view-in-xamarin-forms.aspx at the bottom there is gif that shows the scaling.(I have not got syncfusion)

Any suggestion on how to scale an image when loading a page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scarling is the simple animations in Xamarin.Forms.

You could use the ScaleTo method to animate the Scale property of an Image or Label.

```
  await svgcachedImage.ScaleTo(2, 2000);
  await svgcachedLabel.ScaleTo(2, 2000);
```

**This code animates the Image instance by scaling up to twice its size over 2 seconds (2000 milliseconds).**

Or you could use the `RelScaleTo` method to do the relative scaling of an Image.

```
await svgcachedImage.RelScaleTo(2, 2000);
```

For more details, you could check the MS docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/animation/simple#canceling-animations

You could downlaod the source file from the NuGet for reference. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/userinterface-animation-basic/

Answer (score 0):

you can use the animation

```
Task.WhenAll(
await image.ScaleTo(1.5,5000);
await text.SacleTo(1.5,5000);
)
```

As you know you can animation the obj at the same time. not one after one
so you can use Task.WhenAll();

then you can use the code in

```
protected override async void OnAppearing(){}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.